# Issue while installing click once application using Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, windows-services, clickonce

I tried to install a click once application from my own windows service using 
`InPlaceHostingManager`

added code to install the application while starting the service but an exception throws

> System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException: User has
>   refused to grant required permissions to the application.    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState
>   subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext
>   actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean
>   blocking, TrustParams tp)    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams
>   trustParams)    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements(Boolean
>   grantApplicationTrust)    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements()
>   at WindowsService1.ClickOnceInstaller.iphm_GetManifestCompleted(Object
>   sender, GetManifestCompletedEventArgs e)

the code works fine when calling from a sample windows application.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try two things.

1. Go to services, right click your service and go to properties. Under the Log On tab, check allow service to interact with desktop.
2. Also under the Log On tab, run the service under the specific users account.

Hope this helps!